# Strings, Lists and Maps in properties files - how to define Maps?

Tags: list, properties, dictionary, dropdownbox

If given a .properties file and asked to add a named value for, say, a background colour, one would do something like:

```
page.background.colour=white
```

If further down the track there's a new requirement to define a named list of colours one would either use a comma:

```
page.background.colours=white,grey,black
```

or also possibly a repeated property name:

```
page.background.colours=white
page.background.colours=grey
page.background.colours=black
```

now what would one do to define a named map? Say, there's a dropdown list for colours like:

```
<select name="page.background.colours">
   <option value="#FFFFFF">White</option>
   <option value="#CCCCCC">Grey</option>
   <option value="#000000">Black</option>
</select>
```

The following jumps to mind but somehow there's a feeling that I'm forcing a square bar into a round hole:

```
page.background.colours.#FFFFFF=White
page.background.colours.#CCCCCC=Grey
page.background.colours.#000000=Black
```

Further down, how to ensure the order where white is first and black is last? The following jumps to mind but again, feels wrong:

```
page.background.colours.#FFFFFF.follows=
page.background.colours.#CCCCCC.follows=page.background.colours.#FFFFFF
page.background.colours.#000000.follows=page.background.colours.#CCCCCC
```

I know about XML, JSON and such but I want to stick with .properties file, if possible.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: did u find out the solution ?? even i have this requirement

Comment: haven't found anything that says "this is how everyone must do it" so I'm just using object style dot separated convention:

     colours.red=Red
     colours.blue=Blue
     colours.green=Green

If there are more properties i do:

     colours.red.code=#FF0000
     colours.red.description=Red

and the order is defined by the order in the properties file..